# matlab sum function to python converstion

Tags: python, numpy, matlab, matrix, sum

I am trying to convert this matlab code to python:

```
#T2 = (sum((log(X(1:m,:)))'));
```

Here is my code in python:

```
T2 = sum(np.log(X[0:int(m),:]).T)
```

where `m = 103` and `X` is a matrix:

```
f1 = np.float64(135)
f2 = np.float64(351)
X = np.float64(p[:, int(f1):int(f2)])
```

and `p` is dictionary (loaded data)

The problem is python gives me the exact same value with same dimension (`216x103`) like matlab  before applying the sum function on  (`np.log(X[0:int(m), :]).T`). However. after applying the sum function it gives me the correct value but wrong dimension (`103x1`). The correct dimension is (`1x103`). I have tried using transpose after getting the sum but it doesnt work. Any suggestions how to get my desired dimension?

Comment: Is the shape (103,1) or (103,)?  In MATLAB everything is 2d (or higher), even "scalars". Python has real scalars, and `numpy` arrays can be 0d, 1d, etc  In addition MATLAB trailing dimensions are "outermost", in `numpy` it's the other way around.  And `transpose` does not add dimensions; it just reverses existing ones.  This isn't a `sum` issue.

Answer (score 1):

Lets make a demo 2d array:

```
In [19]: x = np.arange(12).reshape(3,4)
In [20]: x
Out[20]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11]])
```

And apply the base Python `sum` function (which isn't the same as `numpy's` own):

```
In [21]: sum(x)
Out[21]: array([12, 15, 18, 21])
```

The result is a (4,) shape array (not 4x1).  Print `sum(x).shape` if you don't believe me.

The `numpy.sum` function adds all terms if no axis is given:

```
In [22]: np.sum(x)
Out[22]: 66
```

or with axis:

```
In [23]: np.sum(x, axis=0)
Out[23]: array([12, 15, 18, 21])
In [24]: np.sum(x, axis=1)
Out[24]: array([ 6, 22, 38])
```

The Python `sum` treats `x` as a list of arrays, and adds them together

```
In [25]: list(x)
Out[25]: [array([0, 1, 2, 3]), array([4, 5, 6, 7]), array([ 8,  9, 10, 11])]

In [28]: x[0]+x[1]+x[2]
Out[28]: array([12, 15, 18, 21])
```

Transpose, without parameter, switch axes.  It does not add any dimensions:

```
In [29]: x.T          # (4,3) shape
Out[29]: 
array([[ 0,  4,  8],
       [ 1,  5,  9],
       [ 2,  6, 10],
       [ 3,  7, 11]])
In [30]: sum(x).T
Out[30]: array([12, 15, 18, 21])    # still (4,) shape
```

### Octave

```
>> x=reshape(0:11,4,3)'
x =

    0    1    2    3
    4    5    6    7
    8    9   10   11

>> sum(x)
ans =

   12   15   18   21

>> sum(x,1)
ans =

   12   15   18   21

>> sum(x,2)
ans =

    6
   22
   38
```

### edit

The `np.sum` function has a `keepdims` parmeter:

```
In [32]: np.sum(x, axis=0, keepdims=True)
Out[32]: array([[12, 15, 18, 21]])             # (1,4) shape
In [33]: np.sum(x, axis=1, keepdims=True)
Out[33]: 
array([[ 6],                          # (3,1) shape
       [22],
       [38]])
```

If I reshape the array to 3d, and sum, the result is 2d - unless I keepdims:

```
In [34]: np.sum(x.reshape(3,2,2), axis=0).shape
Out[34]: (2, 2)
In [36]: np.sum(x.reshape(3,2,2), axis=0,keepdims=True).shape
Out[36]: (1, 2, 2)
```

MATLAB/Octave on the other hand keeps the dims by default:

```
sum(reshape(x,3,2,2))         # (1,2,2)
```

unless I sum on that last, 3rd:

```
sum(reshape(x,3,2,2),3)       # (3,2)
```

The key is that MATLAB everything is 2d, with the option of additional trailing dimensions, which aren't handled the same way.  In `numpy` every number of dimensions, from 0 on up is handled the same way.

Answer (score 1):

A matrix in MATLAB consists of `m` rows and `n` columns, but a matrix in NumPy is an array of arrays. Each subarray is a flat vector having 1 dimension equal to the number of its elements `n`. MATLAB doesn't have flat vectors at all, a row is `1xn` matrix, a column is `mx1` matrix, and a scalar is `1x1` matrix.

So, back to the question, when you write `T2 = sum(np.log(X[0:int(m),:]).T)` in Python, it's neither `103x1` nor `1x103`, it's a flat `103` vector. If you specifically want a `1x103` matrix like MATLAB, just `reshape(1,-1)` and you don't have to transpose since you can sum over the second axis.

```
import numpy as np

X = np.random.rand(216,103)
m = 103
T2 = np.sum(np.log(X[:m]), axis=1).reshape(1,-1)
T2.shape
# (1, 103)
```